# boto3: ssm client: describe_instance_information: How to filter based on computername

Tags: amazon-web-services, boto3, aws-ssm

I have a list of managed nodes in the fleet manager.

I want to filter the managed nodes using ComputerName field, but in the documentation the filters dont have that

[image]

```
    ssm_client = boto3.client('ssm',region_name="us-west-2")
    managed_nodes = ssm_client.describe_instance_information(
        Filters=[
        {
            'Key': 'ComputerName',
            'Values': [
                'xxxxx-yyyyyy'
            ]
        },
       ]
    )
```

```
[ERROR] ClientError: An error occurred (ValidationException) when calling the DescribeInstanceInformation operation: ComputerName filter Key is invalid.
```

Where as in the aws console. (UI) i can see filtering by computername is there

[image]

Answer (score 0):

`ComputerName` is probably  a **tag**. So you have to filter using tags in `describe_instance_information`.